# Consider Three Nested Functions. Can the Innermost Function Access the Namespace of the Outermost One?

Tags: python, function, scope, nested, namespaces

I tested this out with a program I wrote myself:

```
>>> def f():
    f=['f',1,2]
    def g():
         g=1
         print('this prints out f from f(): ',f)
         print("id",id(f))
         def x():
              x=1
              print('this also prints out f from f():',f)
              print('id',id(f))
         x()
    g()

>>> f()#output
this prints out f from f():  ['f', 1, 2]
id 140601546763464
this also prints out f from f(): ['f', 1, 2]
id 140601546763464
```

From what I learned, the innermost x() function can only access its own local namespace, the enclosing namespace, the global, and finally the built-in namespace. I initially thought that trying to access the list f declared in function f() from function x() would raise an error, as the f() function's namespace cannot be classified as any of the aforementioned elements. After running the program, I realized you indeed can access the list f from the function x(). I don't quite understand how this works though. My guess is that checking the enclosing namespace not only checks the local namespace of the enclosing function but the enclosing function for it as well, in a process that works almost recursively. Can somebody please explain how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Python resolves `names` using `LEGB` rule:(LEGB means Local, Enclosing, Global, and Built-in)

#### Local scope:

- `contains` the names that are defined `inside the function`.
- `visible` only `inside` the function
- `created` at function `call`(If we call the function multiple times each call creates new local scope)
- will be `destroyed` once function `return`

#### Enclosing or nonlocal:

- exists for `nested functions`
- `contains` names defined in the enclosing function
- `visible` in `inner` and `enclosing` functions.

#### Global:

- `contains` all the names defined at the top level of a program
- `visible` from everywhere inside the code.
- `exist` throut the life of code.

#### Built-in:

- `created` whenever we run a script
- `contains` keywords, functions, exceptions, etc that are built into Python
- `visible`  everywhere in the code

The LEGB rule is a rule which determines the order in which Python looks up names.
i.e Python will look the name sequentially in the local, enclosing, global, and built-in scope. And `inner scope` codes can `outer scope` names but `outer scope` codes cannot access `inner scope` names.

When we use nested functions the scope resolving is as follows:

1. check the local scope(inside the function)
2. If not found check enclosing scopes of outer functions from the innermost scope to the outermost scope
3. If not found look the global scope
4. If not found look built-ins
5. Still not found `raise error`